# Making two un-touching parts of an SVG the same layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, svg

I have an online application that handles SVG's. It allows the users to drag and drop them and it also has a colour changing system so the user can change the colour of specific elements of the svg. The system will change each part of the SVG in sequence. So lets say I have the cherry here for example.

[image]

Currently the stalk is regarded as one piece which is perfect but the application picks up the two cherries separately so the user will have to change each cherry colour individually. If they were touching this wouldn't be a problem as it would be all the one shape/layer. In essence I'm basically asking is it possible to "join" "layers" of an SVG without them touching so they are picked up as one shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible in Illustrator.  Select both cherries and do *Object > Compound Path > Make*.

[image]

When you export to SVG, both cheries will be one single path.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#BE1E2D;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M97.3,164c0.2,12.6-13.4,19.3-27.7,19.3s-30.5-3.3-28.8-22.9c2.3-25.3,26.7-19.2,28.8-13.4
    C71.4,141.4,96.9,134,97.3,164z M143.7,147c-2.1-5.8-26.5-11.9-28.8,13.4c-1.8,19.6,14.6,22.9,28.8,22.9c14.2,0,27.8-6.8,27.7-19.3
    C170.9,134,145.4,141.4,143.7,147z"/>
</svg>
```